# What's a good introductory text to ZF set theory?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I've done the usual undergraduate coursework and am interested in learning about ZF set theory. What are some texts that would be accessible to me, and what are the most popular texts in this subfield?

Comment: I've just added a new answer to the question of which this one is held to be a duplicate.  I typed it as an answer to this present question, which got closed just as I was finishing the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like  [Introduction to set theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824779150)